# How to derive Owen's T function?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Owen's $T$ function given by
$$
T(h,a) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{a} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{h^2}{2} (1+x^2)}}{1 + x^2} \mathrm{d}x
$$
can be found all over the scientific literature. It is crucial to computing CDFs, analyzing deep neural networks, and has a lot of application. Despite reading all original papers, searching in all books on CDFs, I could not find a derivation of that important function. Therefore I (have been) searching derivation of how this integral is obtained from integrating up the Gaussian probability density function.

Can you provide one?

Comment: What derivation do you mean?  It is simply an expression.

Comment: No, it made no sense whatsoever to me and I tried to get it myself really hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my derivation:
\begin{align*}
T(h,a)= & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{h}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{ax}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)\right)\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x & y & =tx\\
= & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{h}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}\right)\int_{0}^{ax}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}y^{2}\right)\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x & \mathrm{d}y & =x\ \mathrm{d}t\\
= & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{h}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}\right)\int_{0}^{a}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}t^{2}x^{2}\right)x\ \mathrm{d}t\ \mathrm{d}x & t(ax) & =\frac{ax}{x}=a\\
= & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{h}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{a}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(1+t^{2}\right)x^{2}\right)x\ \mathrm{d}t\ \mathrm{d}x\\
= & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{a}\int_{h}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(1+t^{2}\right)x^{2}\right)x\ \mathrm{d}x\ \mathrm{d}t & u & =\frac{1}{2}\left(1+t^{2}\right)x^{2}\\
= & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{a}\frac{1}{1+t^{2}}\int_{h}^{\infty}\exp\left(-u\right)\ \mathrm{d}u\ \mathrm{d}t & \mathrm{d}u & =\left(1+t^{2}\right)x\ \mathrm{d}x\\
= & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{a}\frac{1}{1+t^{2}}\left[-\exp\left(-u\right)\right]_{\frac{1}{2}\left(1+t^{2}\right)h^{2}}^{\infty}\ \mathrm{d}t\\
= & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{a}\frac{1}{1+t^{2}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(1+t^{2}\right)h^{2}\right)\ \mathrm{d}t
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect!